# Corrupted account name in nodeos log during action pushing

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, nodeos, action

Have an issue with the action push:

`cleos --wallet-url "http://localhost:8889" push action contractx put '["test", "75c88c9593bec6b716f2cb9b60db79282b6f3389a39f3be9adef45e06b379b48"]' -p test`


`Error 3090004: missing required authority
Ensure that you have the related authority inside your transaction!;
If you are currently using 'cleos push action' command, try to add the relevant authority using -p option.`

From nodeos log:

`3054778ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:405           handle_exception     ] FC Exception encountered while processing chain.push_transaction
3054779ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:406           handle_exception     ] Exception Details: 3090004 missing_auth_exception: missing required authority
missing authority of qz3fx4wpln4b5
    {"account":"qz3fx4wpln4b5"}`

Why is account corrupted in the nodeos log? I expect 'test' there.
nodeos tag: 1.0.6;
OS: Fedora 27 x86_64;
compiler: latest from docker `eosio/eos-dev`;

Updated:
Action code:

```
  /// @abi action
  void put(account_name owner, hash_t document_hash) {
    auto key = record_t::primary_key(document_hash);
    print("put owner=", owner, ", key=", key, ", self=", _self);
    // require_auth(owner);
    records.emplace(key, [&] (auto& r) {
      r.owner = owner;
      r.ts = publication_time();
      r.document_hash = document_hash;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Is the contract action attempting to forward an action to another account?  If so, it will require the authority of that account to succeed.  We would need more info on what the contract/action in question is trying to do.

Comment: @JohnHaager, code is attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your action, the emplace call is being used incorrectly.  The first parameter to the emplace call is the account that will be charged for the storage of the data.  In your case, you are using a key that isn't an account name.  The call should look like:

```
...
records.emplace(owner, [&] (auto& r) {
...
```